# jQuery slider and jQuery lightbox not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, jquery-autocomplete

I have a jquery slider and a jquery lightbox. I want both of them to work simultaneously in my site. But i am getting an error. So is there any way to do it?

http://www.highesthits.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/fbox.js

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/scripts/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js

Comment: and your source code looks like... ?

Comment: @JohnSmith @Ant i have provided js which use jquery and have conflict

Comment: What is the wording of your error message?

Comment: only slider is working and fancybox is not working

Comment: Have you tried out the Jquery method 'jQuery.sub()'? Perhaps it will be work if you use two differen instances of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Both jQuery and Lightbox use $.

To use both together without conflict, change the $ in jQuery to something else using the following code: (note that $jQ can be anything)

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now, when writing your jQuery file use $jQ wherever you would normally use $

```
// JavaScript Document
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
 $jQ(document).ready(function(){
   //function on links <a> 
   $jQ("a").click(function(event){
     //add a class to your html
     //<p class="hideMe">
     $jQ(".hideMe").hide("slow");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });//end document ready function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

Plugins:

- jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries
- Nivo Slider for WordPress

I made it work by removing line 32:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

from nivoslider4wp-shop.php located in the \plugins\nivo-slider-for-wordpress\

I hope that helps.